# Anchor links to sections on page do not work on mobile/tablet?

Tags: html, mobile, anchor

I am using anchor tags to set up various sub-links on my website to direct users to specific parts of a page. It's working as expected on Desktop but on mobile and tablet the links just take the user to the top of the page.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
<a href="#three">Three</a>
<a href="#four">Four</a>

<a name="one"></a>
<div class="one"></div>

<a name="two"></a>
<div class="two"></div>

<a name="three"></a>
<div class="three"></div>

<a name="four"></a>
<div class="four"></div>

div {
    height:300px;
    margin:400px 0;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

And [here is a pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GieyB)

Comment: Instead of named anchors, give those names, as an `id`, to the relevant `<div>` elements. Incidentally, a quick read of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) shows that the `name` attribute is obsolete under HTML 5, if that's the doctype you're using?

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas, I did not realize that. I am using the HTML 5 doctype, but the site also has to be compatible back to IE8, would using this method pose any issues there?

Comment: No, it works (from memory) back to, and including, IE7. I'm unsure about IE6, but if you need to support IE6 you have bigger problems...(though there's nothing, that I'm aware of, to say you can't use a named anchor *and* an `id` (though `name` and `id` must be unique amongst their own attributes) to account for both situations).

Comment: Great, thank you! One last question, I am using IDs now and it's working fine as long as I am on the page where the linked section is located, however, if I am linking from a different page(i.e. `href="/about#history"`) it is still not working on mobile. However if I change the link to just `href="#history"` and I click it from the about page, then it works on mobile. These links are in my footer btw. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm it appears as though changing the link from `/about#history` to `/about/#history` allows it to function properly. Is there any reason why I shouldn't format the `href` in this way?